# Find smallest missing integer in an array

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm writing a bash script which requires searching for the smallest available integer in an array and piping it into a variable.

I know how to identify the smallest or the largest integer in an array but I can't figure out how to identify the 'missing' smallest integer.

Example array:

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

In this example I would need 3 as a variable.

Comment: Integers are always +-1? What if the array is `1 5 10 20`?

Comment: I'll just put in the bash tag there.

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Answer (score 5):

Using sed for this would be silly. With GNU awk you could do

```
array=(1 2 4 5 6)
echo "${array[@]}" | awk -v RS='\\s+' '{ a[$1] } END { for(i = 1; i in a; ++i); print i }'
```

...which remembers all numbers, then counts from 1 until it finds one that it doesn't remember and prints that. You can then remember this number in bash with

```
array=(1 2 4 5 6)
number=$(echo "${array[@]}" | awk -v RS='\\s+' '{ a[$1] } END { for(i = 1; i in a; ++i); print i }')
```

However, if you're already using bash, you could just do the same thing in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 2 4 5 6)

declare -a seen
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    seen[$i]=1
done

for((number = 1; seen[number] == 1; ++number)); do true; done

echo $number
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate from minimal to maximal number and take first non existing element,

```
use List::Util qw( first );

my @arr = sort {$a <=> $b} qw(1 2 4 5 6);
my $min = $arr[0];
my $max = $arr[-1];

my %seen;
@seen{@arr} = ();
my $first = first { !exists $seen{$_} } $min .. $max;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do as you ask. It can easily be accelerated by using a binary search, but it is clearest stated in this way.

The first element of the array can be any integer, and the subroutine returns the first value that isn't in the sequence. It returns `undef` if the complete array is contiguous.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @data = qw/ 1 2 4 5 6 /;
say first_missing(@data);

@data = ( 4 .. 99, 101 .. 122 );
say first_missing(@data);

sub first_missing {

  my $start = $_[0];

  for my $i ( 1 .. $#_ ) {
    my $expected = $start + $i;
    return $expected unless $_[$i] == $expected;
  }

  return;
}
```

**output**

```
3
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl one liner:

```
$ echo '1 2 4 5 6' | perl  -lane '} 
           {@a=sort { $a <=> $b } @F; %h=map {$_=>1} @a; 
            foreach ($a[0]..$a[-1]) { if (!exists($h{$_})) {print $_}} ;'
```

If you want to switch from a pipeline to a file input:

```
$ perl  -lane '}
           {@a=sort { $a <=> $b } @F; %h=map {$_=>1} @a; 
           foreach ($a[0]..$a[-1]) { if (!exists($h{$_})) {print $_}} ;' file
```

Since it is sorted in the process, input can be in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("1 2 4 5 6",a)
    for (i=1;a[i+1]==a[i]+1;i++) ;
    print a[i]+1
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
3
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @msrd0 I disagree. Current and future readers should try to figure out what it does by reading available documentation and ask questions if they have any. They'll get a lot more out of that than my spoon-feeding them. It'd be different if the script was in any way complicated/lengthy/interesting.

Comment: For some it'll be better, but if you read documentation for documentation and you don't get the code (no matter how difficult it is to understand, yours should probably be understandable) you get really frustrated and loose fun on the project you're working on

Answer (score 0):

Here's one `bash` solution (assuming the numbers are in a file, one per line):

```
sort -n numbers.txt | grep -n . |
grep -v -m1 '\([0-9]\+\):\1' | cut -f1 -d:
```

The first part sorts the numbers and then adds a sequence number to each one, and the second part finds the first sequence number which doesn't correspond to the number in the array.

Same thing, using sort and awk (bog-standard, no extensions in either):

```
sort -n numbers.txt | awk '$1!=NR{print NR;exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Having fun with [@Borodin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28702801/100754):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.020; # why not?
use strict;
use warnings;

sub increasing_stream {
    my $start = int($_[0]);
    return sub {
        $start += 1 + (rand(1) > 0.9);
    };
}

my $stream = increasing_stream(rand(1000));

my $first = $stream->();
say $first;
while (1) {
    my $next = $stream->();
    say $next;
    last unless $next == ++$first;
    $first = $next;
}

say "Skipped: $first";
```

Output:

```
$ ./tyu.pl
381
382
383
384
385
386
387
388
389
390
391
392
393
395
Skipped: 394
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation on the theme set by other answers.  Values coming in are not necessarily pre-sorted:

```
$ cat test
sort -nu <<END-OF-LIST |
1
5
2
4
6
END-OF-LIST
awk 'BEGIN { M = 1 } M > $1 { next } M == $1 { M++; next }
       M < $1 { exit } END { print M }'
$ sh test
3
```

Notes:

- If numbers are pre-sorted, do not bother with the sort.
- If there are no missing numbers, the next higher number is output.
- In this example, a here document supplies numbers, but one can use a file or pipe.
- M may start greater than the smallest to ignore missing numbers below a threshold.
- To auto-start the search at the lowest number, change `BEGIN { M = 1 }` to `NR == 1 { M = $1 }`.